# Generate next rational number

Tags: rational-number

How can i generate the next rational number into 2 integer variables.
For example, If i have x=3 and y = 2 the next rational number is x=3 and y=3.
The number generation need to be like the next order:

[See the needed order](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Diagonal_argument.svg)

Someone has an idea how can I implement it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n is numerator, d is denominator:

```
if (n%2 == d%2) {
  n++;
  if (d > 1) d--;
} else {
  d++;
  if (n > 1) n--;
}
```